# Suggestions for realtime file transfer between two non-networked PCs running Windows

Tags: file, transfer

To explain the issue:  I work with a SCADA system.  The main control screen is running on a Windows XP system which is not connected to the internet.  We want to keep it that way to avoid viruses and users who get into trouble.

We want to figure out how to allow a user to view the screen of this system remotely (i.e. from an Internet-connected smartphone or PC) without connecting this computer to the internet.

We have another computer running Windows 7 x64 nearby, which IS connected to the internet.

I have tried using IrDA to transfer screenshots from the Windows XP computer to the 7 computer, but the connection is problematic - not reliable.

We need some way of sending screenshots (I have already written a script to capture the screen at defined intervals) between the two computers.  This method needs to be possible with a command-line utility, not a GUI, since it needs to be automated.

My ideas so far:
- IrDA (didn't work, even after spending hours troubleshooting drivers, etc)
- Serial ports (can't find a command-line utility to transfer files)
- Bluetooth (this may be the way to go but I can't find a command-line utility unless fsquirt will do)
- Ethernet/Wireless - won't work - exposes the computer to the internet
- Firewire - same as ethernet
- USB-to-USB - can't find a command line utility
- Proprietary technology (not found anything yet!)

Am I approaching this in the wrong way?  Any suggestions, ideas, insights are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Quite a silly idea: what you if you just set up a video camera on the win7 box pointing to the screen of the win-xp box? It could be a USB camera on a long-ish lead, physically sitting right in front of the win-xp monitor.

Comment: Not silly at all.  I forgot to mention that one in the original post - we had considered that, but I feared someone would accidentally bump the camera...  Thanks!

Comment: Well, there are plenty of wireless IP cameras.  You set the camera in front of the win-xp monitor, plug it into some sort of power supply and connect to an internal wireless network.  From there you send the video feed to the win-7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I just wanted to describe my solution to the problem in the event it benefits someone else.

I decided to try using Bluetooth file transfer since it's wireless and uses tiny USB dongles which don't get in the way.  Here is how I configured this setup and got everything working.

For this to work, you need to purchase Bluetooth dongles which supports 1) the Microsoft Bluetooth stack, and 2) Object Push (OPP) and FTP profiles.
My choice was the Targus ACB10US1 (http://www.targus.com/US/productdetail.aspx?sku=ACB10US1)
This device is based on a Broadcom chipset which supports both the WIDCOMM (included) and Microsoft Bluetooth stacks.

I wanted to send a screenshot from a Windows XP 32-bit machine to a Windows 7 x64 machine.

On the XP machine (Sender), the following items were installed:

1. Targus ACB10US1 USB Bluetooth adapter (DO NOT INSTALL THE WIDCOMM/Broadcom
   DRIVER!)
2. Microsoft Bluetooth Stack & Driver (I used the easy
   installer from http://bluetoothinstaller.com).
3. BluetoothInstaller.com's Bluetooth Command-Line tools
   (http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/)
4. Irfanview 4.33 (http://irfanview.com)

On the Windows 7 (Recipient) machine, the following items were installed:

1. Targus ACB10US1 USB Bluetooth adapter (Use the WIDCOMM driver, which includes the WIDCOMM/Broadcom Bluetooth stack which supports object exchange/ftp profiles)
   Configure the File Transfer folder to a desired folder where the screenshot will be saved.
2. HFS webserver: http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/
   Configured to serve the screenshot file that is received from the Sender computer.
3. A powershell script to update ddns address every x minutes

When sending the first file, make sure to allow the Receiver to receive all files from Sender without needing to be prompted.

To capture the screenshot on the Sender, I used IrfanView's command-line mode with a customized i_view32.ini file.  This ini file adds the current time/date to the bottom left corner of the screenshot.

Here's the [i_view32.ini file](http://hilltop.net/ryan/i_view32.ini)

Here's the [batch file](http://hilltop.net/ryan/screenshot.bat) that continuously runs IrfanView on the Sender PC to take screenshots and transfer the file 'shot1.jpg' using btftp to the Receiver PC.

This method seems to be working fine, however the transfers are very slow (hence there's no need for a 'wait' loop in the screenshot.bat file.)  Each transfer takes upward of 30-45 seconds.  I think there's some sort of timeout in the Bluetooth sending code, rather than it actually taking that long to send an approx. 100kB file.

Optional features:

Create a HTML wrapper file for the raw image on the Receiver PC, with features like auto-refresh, etc. and serve this file with HFS.

I hope this helps someone.  If you have questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the computer on a local network, and don't provide it with the default gateway? Or set-up a local VPN between the two computers. You would only need to install a second nic in the windows 7 pc so that it is able to talk to the main computer.

You could also use a firewall on the XP machine to block all traffic that is not bound for your local network.

just a couple of ideas.

Comment: Also maybe this could help http://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-Windows-Easy-Transfer-Cable/dp/B002L5S6VW

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Shaun.  Unfortunately I don't think the management will allow a network connection to the internet PC, since the SCADA pc is networked into our entire SCADA system.  I am looking for a uni-directional method of transferring the file, so I can assure them there is no possibility of anyone accessing the SCADA system network.

Comment: The USB cable would be great if there was a command line utility for transferring files.  Are you aware of any such utilities?

Comment: you could go real old school and use a serial cable and something like fastlynx http://download.cnet.com/FastLynx/3000-2248_4-10068284.html

Comment: FastLynx is exactly the type of solution I was looking for.  I contacted the manufacturer, and they did advise that Serial communication should work between operating systems.  They also offer a USB-to-USB cable which can be used with their software.  However, it only works between two computers running the exact same version of Windows :(  Also, they confirmed that the software DOES support command-line transfers and can be scripted with no user interaction necessary.  Great suggestion.  I had already ordered Bluetooth dongles (details to come), so if it doesn't work I may have to try this.

Comment: Glad I could help.. remember to add rep!